# Oracle SQL select characters after numeric portion of a string

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, select

I have the string "Serenity Lane - Barbur Boulevard 10920 SW Barbur Blvd Portland, OR 97219" and I want to select the first 13 characters from it :10920 SW Barb

Is there a way to select only the first 13 characters after the first numeric character?  In this example, the first thirteen characters starting at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
regexp_substr(mystring, '\d.{12}')
```

The regex searches for the first digit in the string, and captures it, along with the 12 following characters.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=51a39a464a3666391da55b1a0cbacb22)**:

```
with t as (select 'Serenity Lane - Barbur Boulevard 10920 SW Barbur Blvd Portland, OR 97219' mystring from dual)
select mystring, regexp_substr(mystring, '\d.{12}') string_part
from t
```

```
MYSTRING                                                                 | STRING_PART  
:----------------------------------------------------------------------- | :------------
Serenity Lane - Barbur Boulevard 10920 SW Barbur Blvd Portland, OR 97219 | 10920 SW Barb
```